# Overriding ansible_skip_tags within a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I’ve been able to manage Ansible's control variable that you usually specify on the command line using the [`set_fact` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html); such as

```
- name: Use a default SSH key for this playbook
  set_fact: ansible_ssh_private_key_file={{ whatever_default_location }}
  when: ansible_ssh_private_key_file is not defined
```

But I find myself unable to extend on the skipped tags provided by the `--skip-tags` command-line option. The following playbook

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact: ansible_skip_tags={{ ansible_skip_tags + ['foo'] }}
    - debug: msg="Foo"
      tags:
        - foo
```

gives me the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Foo"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

while the expected output is achieved using `--skip-tags foo` on the command-line:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Is there a way to specify additional skipped tags within a playbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `ansible_skip_tags` is set by the command line options very early, and cannot be overridden. I believe it is used in the initial parsing of the playbook, and as such, cannot be defined from within the playbook itself. Consider the following:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact: ansible_skip_tags="{{ ansible_skip_tags }} + ['foo']"
    - debug: var=ansible_skip_tags
```

This should modify the var, and then print the modified version, however...

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," test.yml --skip-tags=bar -v


PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"ansible_skip_tags": ["bar", "foo"]}, "changed": false}

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_skip_tags": [
        "bar"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As you can see, while the variable appears to have been successfully modified, when printing it, the value hasn't actually been changed. Even if it did change, I think it's too late to be of any use, as the playbook is already parsed at that point.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I debug `ansible_skip_tags` using my syntax (`{{ ansible_skip_tags + ['foo'] }}`) then I see the modifications (at least in ansible 2.7), but still no tags skip.

Comment: No, my bad, you are right, the `debug` task does not show any change to `ansible_skip_tags`. It is only the `set_fact` with the verbose switch.